# Remove Random Item From ArrayList Causing ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, arraylist, concurrentmodification

So, I am running into a bit of a snag with my code and I'm not sure why, or how to get around it. I am writing a method that will take a list of objects and filter it based around some rules. After applying all of the rules, if the list is still over a certain size I need to randomly select items from a specific sublist then and discard the rest. The problem I am running into comes from this block of code:

```
List<Group> filteredList = groupList.subList(0, firstMatch);

if(filteredList.size() < MAX_NUM_RETURNED){
    //This sub list is where I need to pull random items from
    List<Group> subList = new ArrayList<Group>();
    subList = groupList.subList(firstMatch, lastMatch); 

    Random rand = new Random();

    while(filteredList.size() < MAX_NUM_RETURNED){
        int randPos = rand.nextInt(subList .size());
        //remove a random group from the sublist and add it to the filtered list
        filteredList.add(subList.remove(randPos));      
    }
}
```

The `filteredList` starts with 0 - n groups, and if its size is less than the maximum random groups from a subset are added until it hits that number.

The problem is that when the `filteredList.add(subList.remove(randPos));` line is called I get a `ConcurrentModificationException` error and the program halts.

I've looked up what causes this error but all the examples I've seen don't seem to apply to this case. I am not iterating over either list, I am just running the loop based on the size of one of them. Most of what I've seen suggested to fix the `ConcurrentModificationException` has been to create an Iterator and use `remove()` but that only removes the next item in the iterator, and I need to remove a random item each time.

My question is, is there some obvious change I need to make to avoid the concurrency issue, or is this whole methodology fundamentally flawed?

P.S. There may be some inefficient code or some edge cases that haven't been handled yet. I am doing TDD and haven't gotten to all of the test cases yet. The current test this is breaking for is when `filteredList` has a size of 0, and the `subList` contains every group in the original `groupList.` Once this test stops breaking I'll refactor and work on other test cases.

Comment: How did you create `filteredLiist`?

Comment: In that code block you posted, are you iterating over filteredList, or sameCategorySubList?

Comment: where is `sameCategorySubList`? I dont see it in code

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary that was a copy paste error. Edited to be `sublist`. Just renamed it to be a little more generic compared to the actual code.

Comment: Why do you create a `new ArrayList<Group>()` if you replace it in the next line?

Comment: Can you post your full code

Comment: For `java.util.ArrayList`: If `subList.remove(int)` detects a modification on the parent list (that is the `modCount` variables of the parent and sub-list are not equal), then the operation throws a `ConcurrentModificationException`. The question is: While working on the `subList`, are you still working on the parent list? Maybe in some other thread? Where do `groupList` and `filteredList` come from/what are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you modify subList you are also modifying groupList. So if you are iterating over groupList during this process you would get ConcurrentModificationExceptions.

It doesn't sound like you need to modify groupList (since what you are after is the filteredList). So try making subList it's own list rather than a view over groupList:

```
List<Group> subList = new ArrayList<>(groupList.subList(firstMatch, lastMatch));
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Didn't realize that sublists were still linked with the original. Thanks!